# hook scripts tutorials?

Tags: tortoisesvn, hook, scripting

I've been trying to find some tutorials on writing hook scripts, and so far my search has been pretty fruitless. Can anyone point me in the direction of a good source? I've checked the SVN book, but can't find anything that detailed in there (although I may simply not have looked in the right place).
any help is appreciated. BTW: I simply want to make a client side hook that exports data on commit.
best
SWK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching discovered that I can attach a .bat file to the hooks in settings. Not done any batch scripts before, no time like the present!

Answer (score 4):

SVN hook scripts are server-side, not client side. svn runs the hook script on the server where the repository is stored.

luckily, if you are using tortoisesvn, it has some support for client-side hooks. i haven't used it, but here is a link that i found: 
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks